# How can i pass cookies in jmeter?

Tags: php, jmeter

After recording script, I have added 'Cookie Manager'.
2. While running, Cookies are not showed for Request headers in Jmeter and the Connection closed error showing for listener.
But, Browser cookies are passing the request headers in my application.

So, How can i pass cookies in jmeter. kindly give me a solution.
Please refer the snapshot.

[image]
[image]

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to Test Plan an  [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) before your request.

Comment: I have added cookie Manager .But still this issue was open while running jmeter.

Comment: I dont see it in your test plan

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be sending cookie. I would rather expect that you need to extract the value of this `_xsrf` cookie from the `/api/login` request and add the extracted value as `X-Xsrftoken` header.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder"

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```

   and just in case this line as well:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to the request which is failing
4. Make sure it contains the following like:

   - Name: `X-Xsrftoken`
   - Value: `${COOKIE__xsrf}`

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)

Comment: I have updated your mentioned changes..but still this issue open in jmeter