# Not able to login due to '__RequestVerificationToken'

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded ‘Login’ in jmeter.
My Application uses ‘CSRF’ token.

So I added regular expression extractor as in the screen shot.

I have tried different types of patterns:

> "<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([A-Za-z0-9+=/-_]+)">"
>
> "<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" />". etc

But, When I check the response it is like ‘__RequestVerificationToken=%24%7Btoken%7D’

I tried with Xpath extractor also:

> ‘//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']/@value’

I also added cookie manager

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGlPn.jpg)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZGYh.jpg)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtroP.jpg)

Below screenshots are response data(having tokens) for different pages(or paths) before login

This screenshot is for the path ‘/web’(which has the token)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veGyd.jpg)

This screenshot is for the path ‘/Web/Account/Login’ (which has different token)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlrOr.jpg)

But the login is failing due to authentication

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvZDz.jpg)

Question :

1. Am I following the right method
2. Why there are two different token values for two different path (‘/web’ and ‘/Web/Account/Login’)
3. How can I resolve this issue

PS: I have read most of the articles/blogs. Still not able to resolve authentication error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Regular Expression Extractor to the **previous** request to the login page, normally it should have [HTTP GET method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) so amend your test like:

- Open login page (HTTP GET)

  - Regular Expression Extractor (to get `__RequestVerificationToken`)
- Perform login (HTTP POST)

More information: [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)

Comment: Great. Now my request has token. but i am receiving response code 500. what could be the issue.

Comment: **Dmitri T** 
<title>The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken_L1dlYg2&quot; is not present.</title> 


do i need to do regex/css extraction for this also.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use [CSS/JQuery_Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor):

[image: CSS JQuery config]

Comment: I tried using CSS/JQuery_Extractor:, still same issue. '__RequestVerificationToken=%24%7Btoken%7D'

Comment: HTTP request has , HTTP Header Manager(recorded by jmeter), i have added HTTP Cookie Manager(checked clear cookies each iteration) and then i have CSS/Jquery Extractor. Do i need to take care of any other things?
'__RequestVerificationToken_L1dlYg2' this has any effect?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your request verification token is a dynamic value and it needs to be co-related everywhere. Try to pass the co-related variable in the request which is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass cookies in my request along with the above solutions given by Dimitri T and UBIK LOAD PACK.

By modifying jmeter property file, i am successfully passing all the cookies in my request and Login is successful

CookieManager.save.cookies=true

CookieManager.check.cookies=false

If anybody facing issue with '__RequestVerificationToken' forgery token and '__RequestVerificationToken_L1dlYg2' cookies, please follow the below link.

[How can i pass cookies in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45181325/how-can-i-pass-cookies-in-jmeter).

Thanks to DIMITRI T